# How to get excluded data rows when merge in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzPCJ.png)
I try to merge 2 data, the first one is premium users and i got the numbers like in the pic.
I want to ask how to get the other users that is not premium??

example i merge 1,2,3,4 with 3,4,5,6 with inner join and i get 3,4 data how to merge and get only 1 and 2 or the unmatched values data in new df???

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You must provide a sample dataset and your code as **text**, images are not accepted.

Comment: i mean like i merge data 1234 with 3456 with inner join so the data 1,2 is missing right how do i get them in new df

Comment: Looking at your example your `how = 'inner'` should probably be a 'left' instead. Without  an actual data sample its pretty difficult to help troubleshoot your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below:

```
# Perform left merge with indicator

merged_df = pd.merge(clips, premium_user, on='user id', how='left', indicator=True)

# Filter rows from clips that do not have corresponding matches in premium_user

non_premium = merged_df[merged_df['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop(columns=['_merge'])
```

- Left Join : Gives all the rows from  Left df + (Matching rows b/w
  Left & Right Df).
- Indicator : If True, adds a column to the output DataFrame called
  “_merge” with information on the source of each row.
- filter out the left_only rows.
- Drop column “_merge”.